# Unable to change brightness on a toshiba m505

Tags: brightness, toshiba-satellite

I got Toshiba m505 and I can't change the brightness of my screen. I can see the brightness adjusting bar move when I use fn+F6 or fn+F7 keys but nothing happens. I'm using Ubuntu 12.04. I did a lot of search on-line but I can't find anything clear for me to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the kernel needs a parameter. Try this:

Open a terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and give this command

```
gksudo gedit /etc/default/grub
```

at the opened window , search for this line `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"`

and change it to look exactly like this

`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_osi="`

proofread , save the document and then

run in terminal this command

```
sudo update-grub
```

Reboot your PC and see if problem solved.

Comment: @mejalli click the answer as the correct answer.